# If $X$ is continuous and $\det(X(t_0))\neq 0$ then $X^{-1}$ is continuous

Tags: matrices, continuity

Let $X(t)$ a continuous matricial function, $X:I\subset\mathbb{R}\to M_n$, where $M_n$ is the space of all matrices $n\times n$. Suppose that  $\det(X(t_0))\neq 0$ for some $t_0\in I$ then $X^{-1}(t)$ is continuous function.

I tried by definition, but I'm not sure why it's enough that the determinant be not zero just at $t_0$. $\|X^{-1}(t) -X^{-1}(a) \|\leq?? $ any hint is welcome.

Comment: How is $X^{-1}$ defined? $X$ is not assumed to be bijective.

Comment: @DavidLui I think that for each $t$ we compute the inverse of $X(t)$, but I'm not sure why, the problem only say $\det(X(t_0))\neq 0$